# LightCouch doesn't save fields with null value

Tags: java, json, couchdb

I am using LightCouch library in java to save Json objects to the couchdb.
For Jsons I am using Gson library.

Now when I want to save a field with null value it skips that field completly when it saves it to the database.

```
{
   "name" : "KH",
   "lname" : null
}
```

but after I save this to database it only saves the name and skips lname.

In the [API documentation](http://www.lightcouch.org/lightcouch-guide.html) is mentioned

> Fields with null value are not serialized by defualt.

Now I don't know how I can make it to actually serialize the null value and push it to database. Can you tell me how to push a null value ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an awnser here it is :

```
CloudantClient cloudantClient =  new CloudantClient(cloudantDataConnProps);
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.serializeNulls().create();
cloudantClient.dbClient.setGsonBuilder(gsonBuilder);
```

Lightcouch uses default gsonBuilder for serialization, and you need to give him a new one that does serialize null fields